# Can not select object after add column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I add column name is "type" with type = string.
After I add values for table (column type = "android"), then select table, but it can not run, it is not print object:
Device model:

```
 class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :device_token
  validates_presence_of :device_token
end
```

database:

[image]

This is code to get table:

```
 device = Device.find_or_initialize_by(device_token: device_token)
 p device
```

This is log:
  Template Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `templates`.`id`, `templates`.`name` FROM `templates` WHERE `templates`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views: 20.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)

If I update column type = NULL, it can run normally and can print object to see. But if column type = "android", it can not run.
I don't know why, please help me.

Comment: I don't see anything related to Device from the log? Could you add the Device model here?

Comment: @Hoang Phan, I just edited question above.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `type` is a **reserved word** in Rails. Try to change this column's name.

For more reserved words check [Reserved Words in Ruby on Rails](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Yes, it's reason, thank you very much, it take me a lot of time.

Comment: It's specifically used in Single Table Inheritance (I'll explain in an answer for you)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Walerian`, the problem is that `type` is a reserved word in Rails.

In this case, it's reserved for [`Single Table Inheritance`](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) - which basically allows you to [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) models:

```
#app/models/device.rb
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end

#app/models/android.rb
class Android < Device
  ... 
end
```

With the above, you can call:

```
@android = Android.find x
@android.do_something
```

... it will basically *only* query against records in the `devices` table with a `type` of `Android` (all set up by Rails).

--

Thus, if you have a `type` column in your `Device` model, you won't be able to reference it directly.

You'll have to either rename the column or use it as part of an STI structure (which I don't recommend in this instance).